# Passive imputation with mice gives wrong sumscore

Tags: r, r-mice

I am working on a large dataset of 76 persons with 374 variables. My primary outcome variable is a depression sumscore on a depression severety questionnaire (PHQ-9). There is approximately 4% missing data, so I want to use imputation. I have been working with the mice package following the instructions in Buuren, S. van, & Groothuis-Oudshoorn, K. (2011). mice : Multivariate Imputation by Chained Equations in R. Journal of Statistical Software, 45(3). https://doi.org/10.18637/jss.v045.i03. I have tried to replicate their instructions on how to use passive imputation for generating sumscores. However, I get the wrong result. I can't figure out why - I think I have followed the instruction correctly.

I cannot post the data, since it is sensitive, but I am able to replicate the error using this code, which essentially replicates my original code:

```
library("mice")
library("lattice")
set.seed(1234)
m<-matrix(sample(c(NA, 1:10), 100, replace = T), 10)
df<-as.data.frame(m)

ini<-mice(cbind(df, sumScore=NA), max = 0, print=F)
meth<-ini$method
meth[1:4]<-""
meth[5:10]<-"pmm"
meth["sumScore"]<-"~I(rowSums(df[,5:10]))"
pred<-ini$predictorMatrix
pred[, 1:4]<-0
pred[5:10, "sumScore"]<-0
pred[1:4, "sumScore"]<-1

imp<-mice(cbind(df, sumScore=NA), predictorMatrix = pred, method =  meth)
com<-complete(imp, "long", indlude=T)
```

I get the following output:

```
    .imp .id V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10  sumScore
 1    1   1  1  7  3  5  6  1  9  1 10   1   0.9224428
 2    1   2  6  5  3  2  7  3  3  9  5   9   0.6210974
 3    1   3  6  3  1  3  3  7  3  5  1   1   0.3563335
 4    1   4  6 10 NA  5  6  5  5  8  5   1   0.0711464
 5    1   5  9  3  2  1  3  1  2  3  2   1   0.7318026
 6    1   6  7  9  8  8  5  5  7  5  9   5   0.6197897
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your prediction matrix messed up (and I'm not sure if `rowSums` on `df` can be used either - I don't think so since `df` refers to the original data and not the imputed versions).

The prediction matrix should be read as follows: for each row, which variables (columns) are used to predict this variable. Your matrix looks like this

```
> pred
         V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 sumScore
V1        0  0  0  0  1  1  1  1  1   0        1
V2        0  0  0  0  1  1  1  1  1   1        1
V3        0  0  0  0  1  1  1  1  1   1        1
V4        0  0  0  0  1  1  1  1  1   1        1
V5        0  0  0  0  0  1  1  1  1   1        0
V6        0  0  0  0  1  0  1  1  1   1        0
V7        0  0  0  0  1  1  0  1  1   1        0
V8        0  0  0  0  1  1  1  0  1   1        0
V9        0  0  0  0  1  1  1  1  0   1        0
V10       0  0  0  0  1  1  1  1  1   0        0
sumScore  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0        0
```

When a row only contains zeros then it is not using *any* of the variables for imputation. This means that none of the variables are really used for prediction of the `sumScore` and you end up with random noise.

Try this code instead

```
library("mice")
library("lattice")
set.seed(1234)
m <- matrix(sample(c(NA, 1:10), 100, replace = TRUE), 10)
df <- cbind(as.data.frame(m), sumScore=NA)

ini<-mice(df, max = 0, print=FALSE)
meth<-ini$method
meth[1:4] <- ""      # Never impute for these variables
meth[5:10]<-"pmm"    # Use pmm to impute for these
meth["sumScore"] <- "~I(V5+V6+V7+V8+V9+V10)"

pred <- ini$predictorMatrix
pred[, 1:4] <- 0    # Never use V1-V4 for imputation (since you had the same)
pred[1:4, "sumScore"] <- 1  # Use the sum to impute for first 4 (but no method so no point!)
pred[paste0("V", 5:10), "sumScore"] <- 0  # Make sure that we dont impute the "wrong way"
pred["sumScore", paste0("V", 5:10)] <- 1  # Make sure that V5 to V10 are available for sumScore
```

This should give you what you want